# How to replace underscore with a blank space with a regular expression in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, t-sql

I'm trying to insert post codes into my database but getting rid of the underscores. 
I have a table called FeedDataSetMapping that is used to map the fields before they get inserted:

```
INSERT INTO FeedDataSetMapping (

   [source_field]
  ,[database_field]
  ,[template_id]
  ,[conversion_id]
  ,[order_id]
  ,[values_group]
  ,[direct_value]
  ,[value_regex]
  ,[condition_regex]
  ,[split_separator]
  ,[enclosing_character]
  ,[cumulative_field]
  ,[cumulative_format])
  VALUES
  ('manufacturerId','manufacturer_Id',@template_id,0,0,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null),
  ('dealership','leasing_broker_name',@template_id,0,0,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null),
  ('manufacturersDealerId','supplier_ref',@template_id,0,0,null,null,19,null,null,null,null,null),
  ('address1','address1',@template_id,0,0,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null),
  ('address2','address2',@template_id,0,0,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null),
  ('postcode','post_code',@template_id,0,0,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null),
  ('telephone','telephone',@template_id,0,0,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null),
  ('fax','fax_number',@template_id,0,0,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null),
  ('email','email',@template_id,0,0,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null),
  ('website','web_address',@template_id,0,0,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null),
  ('NewCarSales','service_mask',@template_id,0,0,null,1,null,'^(?!(?i:^0$|^n$|^no$|^f$|^false$|^$))',null,null,1,null),
  ('UsedCarSales','service_mask',@template_id,0,0,null,2,null,'^(?!(?i:^0$|^n$|^no$|^f$|^false$|^$))',null,null,1,null),
  ('Servicing','service_mask',@template_id,0,0,null,8,null,'^(?!(?i:^0$|^n$|^no$|^f$|^false$|^$))',null,null,1,null),
  ('Repairs','service_mask',@template_id,0,0,null,16,null,'^(?!(?i:^0$|^n$|^no$|^f$|^false$|^$))',null,null,1,null),
  ('Longitude','longitude',@template_id,0,0,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null),
  ('Latitude','latitude',@template_id,0,0,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null)
```

This already contains some condition regex that in case that this field contains some text it converts it to true or false respectively. 
What I need is a condition_regex that gets rid of these underscores and replaces it with a blank space i.e: `'GDB_A45'` to `'GDB A45'`. I don't know much about regex so any idea would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Tag dbms used. (That code is product specific.)

Comment: Going by the square brackets it looks like SQL Server, which has poor RegEx support.

Comment: It is indeed SQL server

Comment: Why do you need to use regular expressions for this?

Comment: Because I'm using a feed processor system, in which I load a XML file with all this manufacturer's data, the process has be as much automated as possible as it will be used by people with no programming skills so I have to make it work as smooth as I can.

Answer (score 6):

SQL Server does not have much of regular expression support, but in this case I don't think you need it. You can do a simple replace:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET    mycolumn = REPLACE(mycolumn, '_', ' ')
WHERE  mycolumn LIKE '%[_]%'
```

To do this while updating you can use `INSERT ... SELECT` instead of `INSERT ... VALUES`:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (mycolumn)
SELECT REPLACE('my data 1', '_', ' ') UNION
SELECT REPLACE('my data 2', '_', ' ') UNION
SELECT REPLACE('my_data_3', '_', ' ') UNION
...
```

There will be some maximum number of unions you can do, so you should split your inserts into batches with this method.

Or, you could define a trigger on the target table that will do the job for you:

```
CREATE TRIGGER mytrigger ON mytable  
AFTER INSERT AS  
BEGIN
    UPDATE     mytable
    SET        mytable.mycolumn = REPLACE(i.mycolumn, '_', ' ')
    FROM       mytable
    INNER JOIN inserted i
           ON  i.id = mytable.id
           AND i.mycolumn LIKE '%[_]%'

END
```

... where it is assumed your table has a primary key named *id*.

Comment: +
"WHERE mycolumn LIKE '%[_]%'", which will be much lighter on log and time, since it'll only update the rows that needed updating. :)

Comment: Yeah this could work, the problem is I have to do it before the data gets imported, That's why I'm using that FeedDataSetMapping, to insert it in the correct format straight away and avoid to do post insert updates

Answer (score 0):

Well after been thinking a while I got to the conclusion that would be easier if I replace the underscore from the scraped data during the scraping (in the c# code) before I generate the XML file. That would avoid me a lot of headaches. Anyway thank you for your help guys ;)

Comment: So you ask a SQL question, get it answered (comprehensively) then answer your own question using a technology you didn't tag or even mention in the question..